# What is the best solution for develop laravel and vue project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

Please suggest best way to integrate laravel with vue project.

1 - develop separately a frontend VueJS App with a backend Laravel API ?

2 - develop a Laravel App and integrate VueJS inside.

[image]

Which is best option and why?

Comment: I recommend you to have a REST API architecture Laravel backend and Vue as frontend. This will help creation of mobile apps easy in future, which you will definitely have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Different ways to Vue things**

There are different ways we can use Vue with Laravel. We can choose to build a standalone Vue application, Single Page Application, and have Laravel provide the API endpoints, or we can integrate the Vue components into Laravel blade templates as Multi Page Applications. Whichever method you choose is up to you and it depends on your situation.

**Single Page Applications (SPA)**

SPAs work inside a browser and do not need a page to reload. They create a wonderful user experience and can simulate native applications that you can install on your device. The key thing to note is that they load data and markup independently.

This means that for an SPA to change the content on the page, it would never reload, but fetch the data using JavaScript. Although SPAs are fast and require minimal access to the internet after they are loaded, they don’t do too well in search rankings and usually require some extra optimization for SEO.

In our case, the SPA will load on the first call to your application, then swap out the different pages as you continue to use the application with the aid of vue-router. All the data required for each page would be loaded when the components are mounted via calls to your backend API.

**Multi Page Applications (MPA)**

MPAs are the traditional way web applications have been built for years. They typically reload the browser every time data needs to be changed or a request for a new resource is made. You can certainly use AJAX to simplify some MPA operations and reduce page reloads.

MPAs have an edge when it comes to SEO as they are by default crawlable. Unlike SPAs, you do not need to do anything special to make your MPA crawlable. You just need to serve the pages as they are and it will be crawled by search engines unless they are explicitly told not to.

When using Vue in a Laravel MPA, you’ll embed your Vue components directly in your blade file. You can pass data as props to the component. This won’t disrupt the page and its assets and you can easily your normal CSS and JS in addition to Vue.